# GroupLayout does not give required result

Tags: java, swing, layout, frame, grouplayout

Here I add the buttons but none of them is displayed on my frame
also when i add button individually they overlap each other 
what should i do
can some one find problem in my code
I have been referral to this site: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/tpavek/archive/2006/02/getting_to_know_2.html

Code:
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.*;

```
class Abc extends JFrame
{
JButton b[];

Abc()
{
b=new JButton[5];
JPanel jp=new JPanel();
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
{
b[i]=new JButton();
}
GroupLayout layout=new GroupLayout(jp);
jp.setLayout(layout);
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addComponent(b[0])
.addComponent(b[1])
.addComponent(b[2])
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(LEADING)
        .addComponent(b[3])
        .addComponent(b[4]))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
.addComponent(b[0])
.addComponent(b[1])
.addComponent(b[2])
.addComponent(b[3]))
.addComponent(b[4])
);
setTitle("kuvh b");
setSize(1000,1000);
//for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
//{
add(b[0]);
add(b[2]);
pack();
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                                  "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                                //  "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
                                //UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Abc().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code is resulting in the following, which is not what I wanted. please tell me the solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the panel `jp` to your frame if you want it to appear there.  You add buttons 0 and 2, but not the panel that I can see.

Comment: if i want to add button 4(last button) in between button 1 and button 2 then what should i do??

Comment: It is customary, on StackOverflow, to 'accept' an answer that answers your question and/or is helpful.  It gives people who take the time to answer questions points, and is part of how SO works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "between" -- you could mean horizontally, or vertically, or both.  When you create a sequential group, the items you add to it appear in the corresponding order on the screen.

Comment: horizontally between button 1 and 2

Comment: Have you tried something?  What is it that didn't work?  I did reply to the extent of telling you how the sequential groups arrange their elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801110/why-does-a-grouplayout-not-having-a-result-as-per-requirement